# as3 swf file can't execute a php file

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I have an actionscript3 swf file which execute a php file using this code :

```
var load_php:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("php+txt/TIME.php"));
```

This php file will get the server time and write it to a text file for the swf file to read

The problem is this :

The php file didn't execute at all

I tested the same files in a different hosting and they all worked correctly

Whats is the reason for this problem and how to solve it ?

Please tell me if you need more details

**Solved:** There was some naming problems because of today's date 
it was containing zeros but my as3 code was reading it with out zeros so 
it didn't find the file as an example :
file name was: 07-02-2012
my as3 code read it as : 7-2-2012

Comment: Did the php script even get hit? Did a GET request show up in the server's access log when you tried this?

Comment: @Marc B no there is no data passed to the php file when i load it it just contains some php code to write the server time to a text file

Comment: Why not have the php script just output the server time directly to the .swf? seems silly to write it to a file and then have the .swf make ANOTHER request to fetch that file.

Comment: is this all of the code you have? are you using `load_php.load ()'?

Comment: yes i'm using the `load_php.load ()` method

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the script and get the return value when the script is complete, follow the code:

```
var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("phpUrl");
//getting any problem with file not found
phpLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
//Getting any security error
phpLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler, false,0, true);
//When the script is complete
phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler, false, 0, true);
//Execute the script     
phpLoader.load(request);

private function onCompleteHandler():void{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
    trace ("loader.data", loader.data);
}

private function securityErrorHandler():void{/*TODO:*/}
private function ioErrorHandler():void{/*TODO:*/}
```

Remember, your PHP needs to pass some information to AS3 through method POST or GET